# Cordova Push Notifications Plugin Node-gcm for ios

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get push notifications working via the phonegap push notifications plugin, so far i have been able to make it work for android phone but I do not know what to do with the notify.js file to make it work for ios. I have done all the steps to include a provisional profile and it the app registers a ID but does not send a notification.

Here is the code from my notify.js for android

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('ID');
var registrationIds = [];

// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message',"\u270C Peace, Love \u2764");
message.addData('title','Welcome!' );
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); // Shows up in the notification in the          status bar
message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); //Sound to play upon notification receipt - put in the www folder in app
//message.collapseKey = 'demo';
//message.delayWhileIdle = true; //Default is false
message.timeToLive = 3000;// Duration in seconds to hold in GCM and retry before timing out. Default 4 weeks (2,419,200 seconds) if not  specified.

// At least one reg id required
registrationIds.push('ID');

/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

Cheers